# Obtain cross-domain access from iframe to parent window dom that I have no control on?

Tags: ajax, dom, cors, cross-domain, jsonp

I need to press button from my iframe on my parent window, but the parent window is in another domain **AND I have no control over the code of that window**. Is there a way to do it? Jsonp? cors? 
All solutions for that kind of problems involving having control over the parent window code. 
Maybe there is some way - I only need to press the button.
Please post a small code example if possible.I can't modify code of parent window and can't add listener for post messaging for example. I have to access dom from my ifarme and press the button without any code change on parent window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript communicating cross-domain to parent window of iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582211/javascript-communicating-cross-domain-to-parent-window-of-iframe)

Comment: Then what you are doing **simply isn't possible**. good luck!

Comment: Please vote me back up since this is not duplicate

Comment: How is it not a duplicate? You're wanting to communicate from a child iframe to the parent which is on a separate domain. that's what the linked question is asking for too. Post messages are the only option.

Comment: The conditions are different. In the linked question the author has the option to change the code of both parent and iframe. My problem IS that I have no control over the parents window. Otherwise I won't have the problem to begin with. And no question. Maybe I explained my problem a little bit inaccurate. That I will edit right away so if anyone have the same question they would find it. Still I think this is a different question so please vote me back up

Comment: the conditions are different, but the problem and answer are identical. What you are asking for is impossible, for a damn good reason. The fact that this is a duplicate is not the reason for the downvote.

Comment: The problem may be identical but if conditions are different then the answer may be different. The answer is not identical. The linked question has a different answer that mine. It has a solution whereas my question has no solution. I know all the reasons - still hoping for some smart solution. Still don't see a reason to downvote the question.

Comment: it's not useful, it's poorly researched, and it's asking something that has been asked hundreds if not thousands of times before here on this very site using various different wording and conditions, all coming to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, this is impossible.**

You cannot take action on the DOM of the parent of an iframe from the iframe when the parent is of another domain unless you have control of the parent domain. Even if you had control of the parent domain, your capabilities would still be restricted.

If this were possible, sites that use ads, show videos, etc would all be very insecure due to the iframe used for said content being able to read and interact with the parent page.