# how to get parent iframe id in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have two html. One is parent and another is iframe.html.
I am not getting iframe id from child in iframe.html.

It shows cross-origin issue and also implement the postmessage method for cross-origin, but not resolved.
Please suggest how to proceed.

It show below error
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://tpc.googlesyndication.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at findMyId (https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKC7yNXNVxABGAEyCLnNExVMQy5U:61:26)
    at clickHandler (https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKC7yNXNVxABGAEyCLnNExVMQy5U:101:19)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKC7yNXNVxABGAEyCLnNExVMQy5U:88:104)

iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
<style>
img{cursor:pointer;}
img {position: absolute;}
#banner_300by600
{
height:600px;
width:300px;    
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
position: relative;
right:0;
cursor:pointer;
}
#banner_1260by500
{
height:500px;
width:1260px;   
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
position: relative;
right:0;
float: right;
cursor:pointer;
}

.banner_1260by500Img
{
height:500px;
width:1260px;   
background: url(elephant_300x600.jpg) no-repeat;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
position: relative;
right:0;
float: right;
cursor:pointer;
}
#btn_exp
{
 top: 1px;
right: 1px;
}
#btn_clp
{
right: 1px;
top: 1px;
}
.closeBtnStyle{
    position: relative;
    top: -504px;
    left: 1173px;
}
</style>
<script>

         function findMyId() {
             var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");  
                for (var i=0, len=iframes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    if (document == iframes[i].contentDocument ||
                        self == iframes[i].contentWindow) {
                            return iframes[i].id;
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }


</script>               
</head>
<body>

 <div id="banner_1260by500"> 
     <a onClick="setclickurl();"><img src="%%FILE:JPG3%%" id="bigImage" style="position: absolute;"></a> 
     <img src="%%FILE:JPG4%%" id="btn_close" onClick="clickHandler()" style="position: absolute;right:0;">   
 </div> 
<script>        
            function setclickurl()
            {
                window.open("%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%", "_blank");
            }       

             var btnClose = document.getElementById("btn_close");
             var closeBanner = document.getElementById("banner_1260by500");          
            var iframeA = window.parent.document.getElementById("pushdown_1");

            function clickHandler() {
            var iFrameId = findMyId();
                //console.log(window.parent.document.getElementById("pushdown_1"));
              ///iframeA.contentWindow.postMessage('The message to send.', '*');
              window.parent.postMessage('The message to send.', '*');
               console.log("btnClose" + document.getElementById("banner_1260by500").parentElement.parentElement + ";;;;;" );
               console.log("btnClose" + iFrameId);
               parent.document.getElementById("pushdown_1").style.display = "none";
            }

            var messageEventHandlerB = function(event){

               // check that the origin is one we want.
               if(event.origin == '*') {
                  alert(event.data);
               }
            }
            window.addEventListener('message', messageEventHandlerB,false);

            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could solve this with a server proxy so the iframe content also comes from your server. If you have access to the iframe content on the server, you could have a script from your server 1 in the page that knows the ID of the parent. Otherwise you need to redesign so you do not need to know the parent ID

Comment: You use postMessage - perhaps incorrectly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582211/javascript-communicating-cross-domain-to-parent-window-of-iframe